# Android Emulator on MacOS 10.14 has internet only after restarting machine

Tags: android-emulator

I've search the internet far and wide for this issue but didn't seem to have success so far. What I am experiencing:

I've set up the following environment:

1. Android Studio
2. Android Emulator using API 28
3. My OS is MacOS 10.14.3
4. Using it to build a React Native app

At the beginning I didn't have any internet, so I've added DNS of 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 to my System Preferences / Network / DNS. Also I start my avd and tell it to use those dns settings.

After I start my OS fresh and load up the avd I do have internet, loading pages via the Chrome browser. After a little while, though, maybe a minute or two the internet is dropping. Device shows I'm connected to Wi-Fi but no internet. Also Chrome stops loading pages.

Did someone experience the same problem? I've looked through logs and ran avd with `-verbose` option but nothing legitimate shows up.

What I'm suspecting:

- Either the number of internet connections is maxed out (read of such a bug somewhere)
- or file descriptors of the MacOS are maxed out

Nevertheless I don't know how to find out which is it, or how to fix it.

I'd be very happy if someone might be able to help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It's most likely a bug with IPv6 name resolution, removing any IPv6 nameserver in `/etc/resolv.confg` fixes the issue, see https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/155686508#comment3